# Django clean is running on a non-required field

Tags: django, django-forms, django-rest-framework

I have a non-required field in my form called `into_alias`. When form.valid() is called in my view, it is trying to run `clean_into_alias` to validate this field.

However, when no value for the field is provided it is still trying clean it and I get this error:

```
DoesNotExist at /department/b6c1f70de01d488faac5247f54414b5f/merge/delete
{'name_short': ''}
```

**forms.py**

```
class DeptMergeDeleteForm(forms.Form):
      def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        self.department = kwargs.pop('department', None)
        super(DeptMergeDeleteForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

  into_alias = forms.CharField(
    required = False,
    max_length = 51,
    label = mark_safe("""When you delete this department, do you want to merge its members into another department? If so, please provide the alias of the department that you want to merge these employees into "e.g. @tech_support")"""),
    validators=[valid_dept_alias_chars, valid_dept_alias_exists,],
  )

  def clean_into_alias(self):
    dept_drop = self.department

    data = self.cleaned_data['into_alias']
    dept_into = Department.nodes.get(name_short=data) #<------- ERROR -------

    if dept_into == dept_drop:
      raise ValidationError("You cannot merge your members into the same department that you are about to drop ;)")

    # return the cleaned data
    return data
```

Maybe `{'name_short': ''}` is an empty string, not None? I see in my local vars that `data =''`

Answer (score 0):

```
    data = self.cleaned_data.get('into_alias', None)
    if data is not None:
        try:
            dept_into = Department.nodes.get(name_short=data)
            if dept_into == dept_drop:
                raise ValidationError("You cannot merge your members into the same department that you are about to drop ;)")
        except Department.DoesNotExist:
            pass
    return data
```

Comment: thank you for trying. this still errors on name_short in this line `dept_into = Department.nodes.get(name_short=data) `

Comment: yes, `DoesNotExist at /department/b6c1f70de01d488faac5247f54414b5f/merge/delete
{'name_short': ''}`